# Cannot convert value of type 'Location' to expected element type 'String'

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I'm having a problem trying to pass information to an array. But I'm not sure what the problem is. This is my code. I'm trying to show images and information from these particular cities whenever the user clicks on them.

```
var locations : [String]! = [];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let locationDescriptions = buildDescriptions()

    let parisImage = UIImage(named: "paris.jpg");
    let londonImage = UIImage(named: "london.jpg");
    let barcelonaImage = UIImage(named: "barcelona.jpg");
    let mauiImage = UIImage(named: "maui.jpg")!;
    let newYorkImage = UIImage(named: "new_york.jpg");
    let sanFranciscoImage = UIImage(named: "san_francisco.jpg");

    let paris = Location(name: "Paris", image: parisImage!, description: locationDescriptions["Paris"]!);
    let london = Location(name: "London", image: londonImage!, description: locationDescriptions["london"]!);
    let barcelona = Location(name: "Barcelona", image: barcelonaImage!, description: locationDescriptions["Barcelona"]!);
    let maui = Location(name: "Maui", image: mauiImage, description: locationDescriptions["Maui"]!);
    let newYork = Location(name: "New York", image: newYorkImage!, description: locationDescriptions["New York"]!);
    let sanFrancisco = Location(name: "San Francisco", image: sanFranciscoImage!, description: locationDescriptions["San Francisco"]!);

    // This is where the error shows
    locations = [paris, london, barcelona, maui, newYork, sanFrancisco];

}
```

Comment: Why is `locations` annotated as a `[String]!`? You give it an initial value, thus it should be non-optional, and you're trying to assign a `[Location]` to it, so it should (probably) be a `[Location]`. Btw, you also don't need to use a semi-colon at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `locations` as an Array of `String`s, not `Location`s. Just swap out this line:

```
var locations : [String]! = [];
```

with

```
var locations : [Location] = [];
```

And this should fix the type error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding values of type `Location` to an array that should contain `String`.

This will solve the problem

```
locations = [paris.name, london.name, barcelona.name, maui, newYork.name, sanFrancisco.name]
```